# Pushing a new view on a navigation controller from a cell's view controller

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a navigation view controller which navigates between some tableviews and I've just added an "edit" button inside the cells of one of the tables. What I'd like to happen is for the user to tap the edit button inside the cell and for the navigation controller to shunt across a new view where all of that cell's content is laid out for easy editing.

The cell, however, has no access to the navigation controller and cannot push a new view controller on to its stack. How can I do what I want?

Note that I am not using segues and storyboards as it's an old app and I want to continue supporting devices running iOS 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the target of the button to the UIViewController that is already on the stack?

Comment: I didn't know you could do that. I just tried it and crashed the app using this line when the cell is created by the tableview controller... '[cell.editButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pressEditButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];'

Comment: Never mind. I made a silly mistake and it's now working. Much obliged.

Comment: Glad I could help. It is a generally good idea to make the viewcontrollers handle actions etc, not the uielements like cells or views. Especially when it comes to navigation.

Answer (score 0):

If you **don't want to add this new view to the Navigation (Stack)**, Simply use the **PresentModalViewController**

```
// In action method for edit button
- (void)editButtonClicked { 
    EditViewController *editViewController = [[EditViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EditViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:editViewController animated:YES];
[editViewController release];
}
```

Comment: The "self" in my case is the cell where the button is and it doesn't have access to the navigationController.

Comment: If you haven't implemented the NavigationController in your app, then remove the navigationController from the syntax.You would be able to open up with a new view.Hope that would solve your problem.Otherwise, put some code over here, what you are doing actually within the view Transitions.

Comment: The navcontroller is implemented. The problem is that the button, and therefore this code, is in a table cell. I can access the navcontroller fine from the table itself but the cell is one level down and has no knowledge of it.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if you want this, but you can try:

```
// In action method for edit button
- (void)editButtonClicked { 
    EditViewController *editViewController = [[EditViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:editViewController animated:YES];
[editViewController release];
}
```